# R.layout class in standard library and in resources

Tags: android

there is this R.layout class in the standard library, but if I create my own files with xml editor in R.layout directory, they'll be all added to R-file and found from the R-file? This is a bit unclear to me how these go together.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html

Comment: What exactly you did not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the factory android `R` references are stored in a different place than yours. For example, in your java code, you'll access to your references using this:

`R.layout.yourlayout`

But the factory `R` references are accessed through:

`android.R.layout.factorylayout`

Same goes for xml. Your drawables should be:

`@drawable/yourdrawable`

And the factory references:

`@android:drawable/factorydrawable`

So, to sum up, `R` items are stored independently